# How do you reenable esLint squiggly lines after adding Prettier?

Tags: eslint, vscode-extensions, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

## Description

I am trying to configure esLint to work with Prettier in VSCode. I am able to successfully install esLint, but when I add Prettier and add it to extends in the esLint config, the squiggly lines provided by esLint disappear. I have provided more details below.

### Setup Steps

#### 1. Install esLint and VSCode extension

I installed the esLint VSCode extension, and followed the esLint getting started docs to enable esLint. It works exactly as expected. In this example test code,

```js
console.log("This is a test")
```

it identifies three issues which is the **desired result**:

[image: three issues]

#### 2. Install Prettier and VSCode extension

Next, I installed Prettier and the VSCode extension without any difficulty. In this part of the [Prettier Docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html), it says I will need to install [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier).

#### 3. Install eslint-config-prettier

This is where the issue occurs. The installation goes fine, but in the eslint-config-prettier [github page](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) it says:

> Then, add "prettier" to the "extends" array in your .eslintrc.* file. Make sure to put it last, so it gets the chance to override other configs.

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "some-other-config-you-use",
    "prettier"
  ]
}
```

The moment I add this to my `.eslintrc.json` and save the config, the squiggly lines disappear:

[image: no issues]

I am not sure how to resolve this. I went through the docs for esLint, Prettier, and eslint-config-prettier but none of the optional settings listed in the docs are bringing back the squiggles.

### Configurations

#### .eslintrc.json

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {}
}
```

#### .prettierrc.json

```json
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

### esLint Output

```
[Info  - 1:48:20 PM] ESLint server is starting
[Info  - 1:48:20 PM] ESLint server running in node v16.14.2
[Info  - 1:48:20 PM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 1:48:21 PM] ESLint library loaded from: /Users/georgeciesinski/Documents/Repositories/todo-list/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
```

### Additional Info

1. My desired behaviour is for esLint to provide the squiggly lines so I can fix the issues manually. At the end, I will run Prettier from the CLI.
2. I am also using the airbnb eslint config.
3. I am using an M1 macbook running MacOS Ventura in case this matters.

Comment: Check the eslint output channel in VS Code. ESLint does not do anything if it finds a problem in the configuration and prints errors in that channel.

Comment: I added my esLint output to my question. There are no errors in the output from what I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to my query. In short, the configuration works despite my `console.log` test appearing to fail. The `eslint-config-prettier` configuration turns off some esLint rules **as expected**. Per the github docs:

> Extending "prettier" turns off a bunch of core ESLint rules, as well as a few rules from these plugins:

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@babel/eslint-plugin
eslint-plugin-babel
eslint-plugin-flowtype
eslint-plugin-react
eslint-plugin-standard
eslint-plugin-unicorn
eslint-plugin-vue
```

I was aware of this, but I did not realize that the single quotes and semicolon rules were included in this, both of which stopped working when I extended Prettier. Further testing proved that esLint is in fact linting code that doesn't adhere to the remaining `airbnb-base` rules which have not been disabled by `eslint-config-prettier`.